# MASM 5.1a: warning A4057 Illegal size for operand & Link V2.0: Invalid object Module

Tags: assembly, memory, dos, masm

I've been trying to compile a source code for himem.sys which I found in internet for dos but I failed with one warning and one error...

```
...Maked xm286 and xm386 objects without any problem...
H:\OEMSRC>MASM.EXE himem;
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 5.10A
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1081, 1989. All rights reserved.

xm386.asm(342): warning A4057: Illegal size for operand

  48666 + 416309 Bytes symbol space free

      1 Warning Errors
      0 Severe  Errors

H:\OEMSRC>LINK.EXE HIMEM.OBJ XM286.OBJ XM386.OBJ;

Microsoft 8086 Object Linker
Version 3.00 (C) Copyright Microsoft Corp 1983, 1984, 1985

Invalid object module
Input File: HIMEM.OBJ(himem.ASM) pos: C98 Record type: A1 
H:\OEMSRC>
```

Does anyone know how to fix them?
Source code and tools to compile: [Source Code and Tools](https://mega.nz/#!FiYhiACR!veJLeqjFgNg3QhvsRzRdLnBzNRZXWA1kQLx6ebgU17U)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text; post the actual text. Also, you need to show us the code that those messages refer to.

Comment: XM386.ASM is not an object file. Based on memory, command line is `link /tiny himem.obj,himem.sys`. I don't see where xm386.obj is being generated. If there are multiple objects: `link /tiny himem.obj+xm386.obj,himem.sys` .

Comment: @Michael I changed the screenshot for text. I didn't find the masm error but the linker warning is at line 342: ```lgdt qword ptr cs:[GDTPtr]``` I tried deleting it and the warning disappeared. but I'm not going to compile the program without a necessary line. Looking at GDTPtr is: ```GDTPtr equ qword ptr ($+MEM3_Offset) "new line" GDT386 <GDTLen,0,0>```

Comment: @rcgldr Trying to link with that command didn't work... The tiny switch is unrecognized... deleting the tiny part gave me the same "```invalid module object```" linker error

Comment: @rcgldr The old way was to use `exe2bin` to convert the .EXE that the linker generated into a plain binary .COM or .SYS or whatever file.

Comment: @rcgldr Version 2.00 of link hasn't got /? switch result: ```Unrecognized switch: ?```

Comment: If anyone want to test it by his/herself I left the source code and tools download link in the question post, the only requisite to use them is DOSBox and a .rar file extractor

Comment: @RossRidge I have exe2bin ready for use...

Comment: @rcgldr Did you try to use your masm or and link with the source code?

Comment: @rcgldr  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exe2bin

Comment: @JeffLee - I added and update my answer.

Comment: @RossRidge - using link 3.0 then exe2bin produces the same file as using link 5.6 with /tiny option. I tested both. I've been using Virtual PC with MSDOS 6.22 to test this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

In this case ldgt is loading a 6 byte ptr (fword). To get rid of the MASM warning:

```
GDTPtr  equ     ($+MEM3_Offset)         ; no need to declare ptr type here
        GDT386  <GDTLen,0,0>
; ...
        lgdt    fword ptr cs:[GDTPtr]   ; use fword ptr
```

Initialized data is not allowed for segments at fixed address, so use ? instead of 0. MASM 5.10a will ignore the 0, but not MASM 6.11.

```
BiosSeg SEGMENT USE16 AT 40h          ; Used to ...
                org     00A2h
RealLoc1        dd      ?             ; change from 0 to ?
BiosSeg ends
```

The link 3.0 error is caused by 32 bit offsets for two references (see below) to Int13Vector, which are due to "use32" with Zero segment:

```
Zero segment use32 at 0
        org     13*4
Int13Vector label    dword
Zero    ends
```

Changing the "use32" to "use16" solves the link 3.0 error, and results in shorter instructions:

```
Zero segment use16 at 0
        org     13*4
Int13Vector label    dword
Zero    ends
; ...                                     use16          use32
        xchg    eax, [Int13Vector]      ; 6 bytes versus 9 bytes
; ...
        mov     [Int13Vector], eax      ; 5 bytes versus 8 bytes
```

Link 5.6 doesn't have a problem with the 32 bit offsets, but himem.sys will be 6 bytes longer, and switching to "use16" will let you use your current version of link 3.0.

The "help" option for link 3.0 is "link /help" instead of "link /?", but it doesn't show much.

---

Using MASM 6.11 and Link 5.6, (/AT = tiny, /Zm = MASM 5.0 syntax):

```
ml /AT /Zm himem.asm
ren himem.com himem.sys
```

MASM 6.11 optimized a conditional jump to a short at line 114 in xm386.asm. Changing the code to use short results in the same size file using MASM 5.10 / Link 3.0 or MASM 6.11 / Link 5.6, but there are some minor differences, like the order of segment and operand size prefixes (ES: and DB 066H (for 32 bit operand) get swapped).

```
        jz      short MEM3_Exit                 ; Exit immediately if zero
```

Comment: could you leave a download link for Masm 6.11 and link 5.6 please? I can't fin them any where...

Comment: @JeffLee - do a web search for "masm 6.11 download" or "masm 611 download", I got several matches. The download should include the linker. For the rest of the 16 bit toolset (C/C++ compiler) search for "visual c / c++ 1.52", which may or may not include MASM 6.11. The toolset runs in 32 bit mode using a dos extender (included) or Windows XP (could be Virtual PC in XP mode), and are mostly used to produce 16 bit code.

Comment: Using ml /AT /ZM himem.asm gives me an Unrecognized Switch Error: "R"

Comment: @JeffLee - that should just be a warning and ignored. If it's causing an error, then use "ml /C /AT /ZM ... " followed by "link ... " .